# Titanium Alloy - 'Global' Listener

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium, titanium-alloy, appcelerator-alloy

I have multiple windows that 'require' livebar so that the entire bar persists over all windows. However, whenever the 'change' function is called, it works and logs, however my $.livebar_datalbl.text fails with the following error: "undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.livebar_datalbl.text = 'State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')'')"

Am I structuring the code incorrectly or missing something?

**index.js**

```
(function constructor() {
    audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
        url: 'https://allthingsaudio.wikispaces.com/file/view/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3/139190697/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3',
        allowBackground: true
    });

    audioPlayer.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');
    });

    audioPlayer.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        $.livebar_datalbl.text = 'State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')';
        Ti.API.info('State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')');
    });

    window = Alloy.createController('listen').getView();
    window.open();
})();
```

**livebar.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <View class="livebar">
        <View class="livebar_livelblcontainer">
            <Label class="livebar_livelbl">LIVE</Label>
        </View>
        <Label class="livebar_datalbl" id="livebar_datalbl">HELLO WORLD</Label>
        <ImageView id="livebar_playpausebtn" class="livebar_playpausebtn"/>
    </View>
</Alloy>
```

**livebar.js**

```
$.livebar_playpausebtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (audioPlayer.playing || audioPlayer.paused) {
        audioPlayer.stop();
        if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android')
        {
            audioPlayer.release();
        }
    } else {
        audioPlayer.start();
    }
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
    Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    $.livebar_datalbl.text = 'State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')';
    Ti.API.info('State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `audioPlayer.addEventListener` event will only listen to events in the controller that you have created the audioPlayer in, in this case **index.js**. In your example the `audioPlayer.addEventListener` events in **livebar.js** have no effect as there is no audioPlayer to add event to.

If you would like to have the audioplayer in **index.js** and then have the livebar be updated and still keep the livebar in its own view+controller you will need to fire events across the controllers. To do this you can make use of `Ti.App.fireEvent`

You can read more here - Search for the **"Application-Level Events"** Section

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Event_Handling

You could do something like below.

Remember to be careful with App wide event listeners, you should always remove 
those when you are done with them via the function below

```
Ti.App.removeEventListener("eventlistenername", eventfunctionname);
```

**index.js**

```
(function constructor() {
    audioPlayer = Ti.Media.createAudioPlayer({
        url: 'https://allthingsaudio.wikispaces.com/file/view/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3/139190697/Shuffle%20for%20K.M.mp3',
        allowBackground: true
    });

    audioPlayer.addEventListener('progress', function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('Time Played: ' + Math.round(e.progress) + ' milliseconds');
    });

    audioPlayer.addEventListener('change', function(e) {

        // set livebareText
        var livebareText = 'State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')';

        // fire app wide event
        Ti.App.fireEvent("app:updateLivebar",livebareText);

        Ti.API.info('State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')');
    });

    window = Alloy.createController('listen').getView();
    window.open();
})();
```

**livebar.js**

```
$.livebar_playpausebtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    if (audioPlayer.playing || audioPlayer.paused) {
        audioPlayer.stop();
        if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android')
        {
            audioPlayer.release();
        }
    } else {
        audioPlayer.start();
    }
});

// Add App eventlistener to listen for updateSingleProgessBar
Ti.App.addEventListener("app:updateLivebar", updateLivebar);

function updateLivebar(livebarText){

    $.livebar_datalbl.text = livebarText;
    Ti.API.info('State: ' + e.description + ' (' + e.state + ')');

}
```

Comment: David - Thank you. After some minor tweaks this works nicely. However, as livebar.js is 'included' on two other windows, every time I switch between windows it adds the listener again, so after a few back and forths I might have it updating the label 10, 20, 30 times. (Not a problem as you wouldn't see that, I'm thinking more memory/CPU usage).

Do you have any suggestions on this or shall I just destroy the listener on window change?

Comment: There would be a few ways to solve that problem.

1. Only include the view in one window, but that might not be possible.
2. Add a listener to the window close event, and then have a function that removes that run `Ti.App.removeEventListener` when the view is closed

Comment: Thanks! I had problems with this but potentially it's the way I was trying to design and layout the app. It made me decide to just give up with trying it this way and go down the proper route and I've now started implementing this in Swift (native) and will look at Java for Android later. Thanks again!